# how to save the absolute path of a file as a string with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, absolute-path

I have this line of code and it picks all the files in a folder.

```
<input type="file" id="filepicker" name="fileList" (change)="saveFolderLocation($event)" webkitdirectory/>
```

I want to know the directory of the files. So I use the following code to get the path of the first file, but I can only get its relative path, I want the absolute path, so that I can save it as a string later.

```
 public saveFolderLocation(event: Event){
   const element = event.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement;
   let files = element.files;
   console.log(Array.from(files)[0]['webkitRelativePath']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the File input documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file. You will not be able to capture the absolute path to prevent malicious software.

Comment: Are there any libraries, that can help me go around this?